# Can you get Yii 2 to automatically display the form errors in a custom location?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using `Yii 2` and currently to display the errors from submitting a form I do something like this:

```
$errors = general::formatErrors($model->errors);
```

**formatErrors** is basically just a method that wraps each error in the array in a

tag; then I do something like:

```
return $this->render('login', ['model' => $user, 'errors' => $errors]);
```

Then in the view:

```
<?php echo ($errors) ? '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">' . $errors . '</div>' : ''; ?>
```

I don't have an issue doing it like this as it's pretty easy and straightforward; however Yii only seems to display errors under each form field if that field has an error; so we get a duplication of errors.

I would prefer to display all my errors at the top together. I noticed you can use the `enableError` property on fields; but I don't really want to have to apply that to every single field in the form - but I can't find a similar property for the whole form?

So if I can't disable error display in an easy manner, is there anyway to customize where the errors display in your view?

Someone told me about the [inputTemplate](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield.html#$inputTemplate-detail) but it seems that is only tied to a field and not the whole form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it another way.
First you do not have to pass to the model the errors. The model already knows the errors and it's hasErrors / getErrors function will return to you all the errors.

Also http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#errorSummary()-detail the active form can already create the summary for you.

So you can create the form as:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'fieldConfig' => [
                        'template' => "<div class=\"row\">
                                            <div class=\"col-xs-6\">{label}</div>\n<div class=\"col-xs-6 text-right\">{hint}</div>
                                        \n<div class=\"col-xs-12\">{input}</div>
                                        </div>",
                    ],
                ]); ?>
    ...........

    <?=$form->errorSummary($model);?>
```

This is just an example of a form layout without the {error}, change to suit your own form.

If you want to hide / change the text "Please fix the following errors:" you can play around with the options in errorSummary. The official documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#errorSummary()-detail tells you that there are 2 options header and footer that you can change to change the text

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea how to hide the ones output below the fields?

Comment: Also...... can you edit the template somehow for the error summary? I don't want the text "Please fix the following errors:" to show.